# packer with ansible provisioner

Tags: ansible, packer

i am using packer for the automated image creation on openstack. i am using ansible for provisioning. 
my packer machine is different from my ansible machine and in this case how can i use the provisioner:

```
"provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "ansible",
      "playbook_file": "./playbook.yml",
      "extra_arguments": "-vvvv"
    }
  ],
```

`playbook.yml` is in the different machine. how can i redirect packer to my ansible machine ip address and the location of the yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't. Ansible control machine needs to be the same as the Packer host.

Answer (score 0):

sure, thanks for the reply. however when I am doing that the ansible playbook is throwing an error that "it must be run as root" so where do I need to mention that since I am using the cloud image of centos where the username is centos and my yaml file as follows:

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  user: centos
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

in my builder i have mentiooned the user:centos